# Erro ao inserir registro em tabela filha com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Olá, eu tenho as seguintes tabelas:

|-----tb_usuario---------------------------------------------|
|id - nome - login - senha - flag_ativo - permissao|
|----------------------------------------------------------------|

|--------tb_regional----------|
|id - nome - login -  senha|
|---------------------------------|

|------tb_regional_usuario-------|
|tb_regional_id - tb_usuario_id|
|---------------------------------------|

E estou tentando inserir os registros na tabela 'tb_usuario' e na tabela 'tb_regional_usuario' em uma função 'cadastra_usuario()' porém a query que deveria fazer a inserção na tabela 'tb_regional_usuario' falha retornando o seguinte erro: **Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails**. Enquanto a query que insere usuário é executada com sucesso e o usuário é cadastrado no banco. Pelo que pesquisei isso quer dizer que eu tentei inserir um registro 'tb_usuario_id' que não existe na tabela pai mas a função 'mysqli_insert_id()' retorna justamente o id do registro que é inserido no banco quando a função é executada. Abaixo segue a função para melhor entendimento:

```
<?php    

include_once(__DIR__.'/../models/conexao.php');

//Função que cadastra usuários
function cadastra_usuario($nome, $login, $senha, $permissao, $flag_ativo, $regional)
{
    $conn = conectar();

    $query =  "INSERT INTO `tb_usuario` (`nome`, `login`, `senha`, `permissao`, `flag_ativo`)"
            . "VALUES ('$nome', '$login', MD5('$senha'), '$permissao', '$flag_ativo');";

    mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    $usuario_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

    //echo $query.'<br>';

    foreach ($regional as $index=>$valor)
    {
        $query2 = "INSERT INTO `tb_regional_usuario`(`tb_regional_id`, `tb_usuario_id`) "
                . "VALUES ('$index', '$usuario_id');";

        mysqli_query($conn, $query2) or die(print_r(mysqli_error($conn)));

        //echo $query2.'<br>';

        $valor++;

        //unset($valor);
    }


    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) != 0)
    {
        header("Location: ../../views/menu.php?pag=usuarios");

        //var_dump(mysqli_insert_id());
        //var_dump(mysqli_affected_rows($conn));

        $_SESSION['status_registro'] = "Registro inserido com sucesso!";
    }
}
```

Agradeço bastante se puderem me ajudar a visualizar o que tem de errado com o código.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que erro seja no `$index`
Quando você faz o `foreach` o index passa a ser um contador e não o valor da regional.
Tente trocar o `$index` por `$valor` como no exemplo abaixo.
*Ou `$valor['id']` se for array.

Ou `$valor->id` se for objeto.*

```
<?php    

include_once(__DIR__.'/../models/conexao.php');

//Função que cadastra usuários
function cadastra_usuario($nome, $login, $senha, $permissao, $flag_ativo, $regional)
{
    $conn = conectar();

    $query =  "INSERT INTO `tb_usuario` (`nome`, `login`, `senha`, `permissao`, `flag_ativo`)"
            . "VALUES ('$nome', '$login', MD5('$senha'), '$permissao', '$flag_ativo');";

    mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    $usuario_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

    //echo $query.'<br>';

    foreach ($regional as $index => $valor)
    {
        $query2 = "INSERT INTO `tb_regional_usuario`(`tb_regional_id`, `tb_usuario_id`) "
                . "VALUES ('$valor', '$usuario_id');";

        mysqli_query($conn, $query2) or die(print_r(mysqli_error($conn)));

        //echo $query2.'<br>';

        $valor++;

        //unset($valor);
    }


    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) != 0)
    {
        header("Location: ../../views/menu.php?pag=usuarios");

        //var_dump(mysqli_insert_id());
        //var_dump(mysqli_affected_rows($conn));

        $_SESSION['status_registro'] = "Registro inserido com sucesso!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Acontece que quando dou um vardump em '$regional' os index que estão contidos nele são exatamente os mesmos das regionais cadastradas no banco. Abaixo segue a query gerada pela função que acabei de testar: 

INSERT INTO `tb_usuario` (`nome`, `login`, `senha`, `permissao`, `flag_ativo`)VALUES ('Ozzy Osbourne', 'ozzsabbath', MD5('blackfuneral'), '2', '1');
INSERT INTO `tb_regional_usuario`(`tb_regional_id`, `tb_usuario_id`) VALUES ('3', '31');
INSERT INTO `tb_regional_usuario`(`tb_regional_id`, `tb_usuario_id`) VALUES ('4', '31');

Comment: Pode mostrar o vardump ? O erro esta no foreach.